# Range space of two transposed marices that one is greater than the other.

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

$\def\realnumbers{\mathbb{R}}$
$ Let~B_1∈{\mathbb{R}}^{n*m_1} and~B_2∈{\mathbb{R}}^{n*m_2}$
and assume that $ B_1B_1^T\le~B_2B_2^T$
$Show~that~$ $$R(B_1B_1^T)\subseteq~R(B_2B_2^T)$$ and thus $$ R(B_1)\subseteq~R(B_2)$$
I started with The definition of range space where $$ R(B_1B_1^T) = [xB_1B_1^T;x\in{\mathbb{R}}^{n}]$$
But I am just not sure how to relate the comparison mathematically. Logically I'd say well the rank of $ B_1B_1^T\le~rank~of~B_2B_2^T$ Then relate that to the range space which the rank is its dimension.

Comment: That image is pretty much unreadable... Can you transcribe it in your post, preferably using MathJax?

Answer (score 1):

Let $P_i=B_iB_i^T\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ (positive semidefinite matrices) such that $P_2=P_1+P_3.$

$\ker P_2\subset\ker P_1$ and $(\ker P_i)^\bot=\operatorname{im}(P_i^T)=\operatorname{im}(P_i)$ hence $\operatorname{im}(P_1)\subset\operatorname{im}(P_2).$

Comment: I am not very familiar with ker is there anyway we can traditionally go about this.

Comment: [$\ker$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)) is, more than "traditional", an *unavoidable* notion in linear algebra.